# Retrieving Angularjs Variable output

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<div ng-controller="SearchResultsTextCtrl" class="search-text search-results">
<div class="title" ng-if="showSearchResultsText && !showNoResultsMsg">
            <div id="searchKeyword" class="main">{{searchKeyword}}</div>
            <div class="num">Your search for <span style="font-style: italic">"{{searchKeyword}}"</span> returned <span id="searchResultCount">{{totalResults}}</span> {{searchResultsText}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="no-results" ng-if="showNoResultsMsg">
            <div class="title">SORRY NO RESULTS FOUND</div>
            <p>Please try again</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

I'm new to angular so can someone point me in the right direction to how to get the search results from the #searchKeyword dom. Everytime I get the document via jquery('#searchkeyword').html() I get the angular variable of {{searchKeyword}} instead of margret river.

Comment: You should be able to access the variable inside the scope.
e.g. `$scope.searchKeyword`

Comment: I can't access the raw codes and add a model to the div because I'm using Adobe's Dynamic tag management to retrieve the searched word. So the only way I can access the div value at this point is $('#searchKeyword').html() but it always returns {{searchKeyword}}

Comment: Provide a fiddle or plunker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use scope for that you can use

> $scope.searchKeyword

or you can use add different model name on the element

```
<div id="searchKeyword" ng-model="ngModel "class="main">{{searchKeyword}}</div>
```

And in controller:

```
$scope.ngModel
```

Comment: I can't access the raw codes and add a model to the div because I'm using Adobe's Dynamic tag management to retrieve the searched word. So the only way I can access the div value at this point is $('#searchKeyword').html() but it always returns {{searchKeyword}}

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of ngModel in the html markup (two way binding of Angular) and have searchKeyWord as a scope variable. Something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="SearchResultsTextCtrl" class="search-text search-results">
<div class="title" ng-if="showSearchResultsText && !showNoResultsMsg">
            <input type="text" id="searchKeyword" ng-model="searchKeyword" class="main" />
            <div class="num">Your search for <span style="font-style: italic">"{{searchKeyword}}"  </span> returned <span id="searchResultCount">{{totalResults}}</span> {{searchResultsText}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="no-results" ng-if="showNoResultsMsg">
            <div class="title">SORRY NO RESULTS FOUND</div>
            <p>Please try again</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

and in controller you will get the updated searchKeyword value.

[Documentation on two way binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/databinding)

[Documentation on $scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)